# finally block handling when using @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exceptionhandler

**Situation**

I'm having a controller class with try catch exception handling within the controller class. Lately I have been trying to move the traditional try catch block to spring's @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler.

However my controller is having a finally block. So I have been looking all over to see how finally block can be handled while using @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler method. I'm unable to find any solution to handle the situation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're allowed to have a finally block without a catch block. Just leave the finally block in the controller, where it belongs.